# SCP from one external server to another

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scp

I am trying to use SCP on my local server to copy a file from one remote server to another remote server (both remote servers use a custom port (xxxx)

I am trying:

```
scp -r -P xxxx root@xxx.xxx.xxx.111:/home/myimages/images.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xxx.222:/home/myimages/images.tar.gz
```

But I get the following error:

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.222 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I presume that you can ssh to xxx.xxx.xxx.222 normally?

Comment: Yeah, I can ssh to all servers from all servers

Comment: Cross posted here: http://serverfault.com/questions/81650/scp-from-one-external-server-to-another

Answer (score 18, accepted):

did you check that direct authentication works from  first remote host to the second one?

`scp user@host:/file user@otherhost:/otherfile` is shorthand for

`ssh user@host scp /file user@otherhost:/otherfile`

which leeds me to think:

`ssh -p XXX user@host scp -P XXX /file user@otherhost:/otherfile` might work.

Comment: Yeah, i have ssh'd to both all servers from each server :(

Comment: Good point, just because you can see xxx.222 doesn't mean that xxx.111 can.

Comment: It is a good point, but I have already checked that, any other suggestions?

Comment: The ssh then the scp does what i need it to.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `scp` doesn't realize that the special port should also be used on the second server. You could try to explicitly call `ssh` to start the remote `scp` transfer:

```
ssh -P xxxx user@host scp -P xxxx /file user@otherhost:/otherfile
```

Answer (score 3):

Define the servers in your `.ssh/config file`, for example:

```
Host foobar
User youruser
Port 2222
Hostname the.real.hostname

Host foobar2
User youruser
Port 2222
Hostname the2.real.hostname
```

You can then simply do:

```
scp foobar:file foobar2:
```

and it will use the defined custom ports.

Answer (score 3):

I've got remote servers that cannot see each other, but my local server can see both.
The ssh daemon in the remote servers are listening in different non-standard ssh ports. 
This is how I get this done:

```
ssh -p 111 userA@remote1 'cat myfile' | ssh -p 222 userB@remote2 'cat - > myfile'
```

The second ssh command asks for the password first, then remote1 asks for password for userA.
You may have this automated if you have set up ssh authorized keys, which is not the case in my environment.