# scp can't access SSH alias: Name or service not known

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I want to move a directory from one host to another. This is my command:

```
scp -r host1:filepath host2:filepath
```

I get this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname host2: Name or service not known
lost connection
```

`host1` and `host2` are present in my `~/.ssh/config`, and I can connect to them with `ssh host1` and `ssh host2` without problem.

Why does scp fail to connect to `host2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that `host1` needs to be able to connect to `host2` for this to work. The details are [in another answer](https://superuser.com/a/66950/487098).

Comment: `scp -r -3 host1:filepath host2:filepath` will work